# Change time format in Mercurial Kallithea

Tags: mercurial, kallithea

I used kallithea version 0.1. On summary page are showed commits with timestamp like "23 minutes and 33 seconds ago" or "1 day ago" or "1 month ago", that's strange if you looking for something at specific time.

Is there possibility to change format like this "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm" ??